# colordiff -y does not color output in CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos-7

For the life of me, I cannot get `colordiff` to output color to the terminal. I feel like I am missing something simple.

[Example of no color output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J1C3.png)

Environment:

- `cat /etc/centos-release` = CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
- `colordiff --version` = diff (GNU diffutils) 3.3
- `sudo yum info diffutils` = Version     : 3.3 | Release     : 5.el7
- `sudo yum info colordiff` = Version     : 1.0.13 | Release     : 2.el7
- Terminal = PuTTY Release 0.74
- OS = Microsoft Windows 10 Home | Version 10.0.19041 Build 19041

The specific command I am trying:

- `\colordiff -y --left-column /opt/projects/openidm/subscribers/conf/authentication.json /opt/projects/git/subscribers/conf/authentication.json`

Commands I have tried but will not output color:

- `\colordiff -y --left-column <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y --left-column --difftype=diffy <File-1> <File-2>`

Commands that will output color in the terminal for all files:

- `\colordiff <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y --ignore-trailing-space <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y --ignore-trailing-space --suppress-common-lines <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y --left-column --ignore-trailing-space --suppress-common-lines <File-1> <File-2>`

Commands that output color depending on the type of differences in the files:

- `\colordiff -y --left-column --suppress-common-lines <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y --left-column --suppress-common-lines --difftype=diffy <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y --suppress-common-lines <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y --suppress-common-lines --difftype=diffy <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\colordiff -y --difftype=diffy <File-1> <File-2>`
- `\diff -y  <File-1> <File-2> | \colordiff`
- `\diff -y  <File-1> <File-2> | \colordiff --difftype=diffy`

Note: I have preceded most commands with a `\` to make sure no aliases are involved.

Update: After trying multiple files for comparison, it turns out that the original files I was comparing had a trailing space that was causing an issue. That said, the issue still requires that I add `--suppress-common-lines` to my original command, even though in my case, that only removes 2 lines from the output.

Update2: I submitted a bug report to the maintainer [here](https://github.com/daveewart/colordiff/issues/47). Hopefully that will help someone in the future.

[Only working edge case for -y --left-column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nHtp.png)

Comment: Why do all commands start with an anti-slash?

Comment: To make sure that no commands have any kind of alias interfering. I can remove them from the question if that is confusing.

Comment: I don't know why colordiff isn't working for you, perhaps bad version in the repository you are using. An alternative package is [icdiff](http://manpages.org/icdiff).

Comment: I will give `icdiff` a try.
But, I find it weird that it works when I use `ignore-trailing-space`

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the suggestion. But, sadly. I do not have access to `icdiff` It is not included in CentOS 7 repos. Or at least the ones that have been set up in this environment. I am not allowed to add any non-supported repos.

Comment: Weird, `icdiff` exists in the Ubuntu repository. Does colordiff work without `ignore-trailing-space` if there are no trailing blanks in the diffed files?

Comment: CentOS is weird that way. It's for support reasons I believe. I will give that a try as I had not thought about that.

Comment: Whatever the bug you have found, in your place I would create an alias for `colordiff -y --ignore-trailing-space` and forget about it.

Comment: I will do that. But, to give you an update. Trying a file without a trailing space in it allowed the command to work without the option. `\colordiff -y --left-column --suppress-common-lines <File-1> <File-2>` but still does not work without the `--suppress-common-lines` even though in my case, the only difference is 2 lines. Just weird all around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your tests, the current version of `colordiff` in CentOS has a weird
bug with files containing blanks at the end of the line.

While waiting for a fixed version of `colordiff`, an immediate fix would be to create
an alias to `colordiff -y --ignore-trailing-space`.